# How can I safely use Get-Credential to obtain a username and password for a set period of time for use as command line arguments?

Tags: credentials, powershell

Credentials in the form of SSH keys can be stored in memory using SSH Agent;  However, if clicking the wrong link, or running a malicious program they can also be snatched from memory and sent somewhere else; which is why `ssh-add` offers the `-t` option to specify how long keys will be kept in memory before one is required to reload them hopefully using a passphrase.

Powershell has simalar functionality using secure strings but we are discouraged from using it, especially when writing credentials to disk; but Powershell offers another option in which you can prompt a user for their username and password, store  it in a variable that will last the length of the powershell session: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069785/use-encrypted-password-for-plink-putty

Is it possible to unload credentials gathered from Get-Credentials from memory after a set period of time, similar to `ssh-add`?

Comment: What if I use a timers.timer / action to clear the variable storing the Credentials?

Comment: Then I would be storing the credentials in memory, but after a specified period of time, the action could run something like `Clear-Variable` on the credentials input from the prompt, and then if somebody got into my Powershell session after the timeout they wouldn't find the variable.

Comment: There's a timer example here: https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/creating-a-timer-event-in-powershell/